# get the correct url for an folder in wp-includes wordpress

Tags: php

I have added a folder (json) to `wp-includes` with a file inside called `users.json`. I am trying to write to this file but am getting the following error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable
>   connections

I have been referencing it like the following in my php:

`$file = "http://www.fakeurl.com/wp-content/json/users.json";`

I believe I need to reference as per the name on the server. Is there a built in way to get this in wordpress?

Something like `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sad you put the json in `wp-includes`, but in the url you wrote `wp-content`. So I give you the code for getting the server path for both folders:

```
// wp-includes
$file = ABSPATH . WPINC . '/json/users.json';

// wp-content
$file = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/json/users.json';
```

You can find many WordPress constants (like `ABSPATH`, `WPINC`and `WP_CONTENT_DIR` on http://wpengineer.com/2382/wordpress-constants-overview/